# Rails 3 + Rspec 2 + Autotest: Autotest style Rspec2 doesn't seem to exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, autotest

I updated my ruby gem and suddenly Autotest stopped to work..

After many attempts to fix without any debug information, I know have this:

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails_rspec2
You don't have i18n installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Autotest style autotest/rails_rspec2 doesn't seem to exist. Aborting
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Does `bundle exec autotest` work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case `bundle update` solves the issue. (with rspec 2.6.0, rspec-rails 2.6.1 and rspec-core 2.6.3 now)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Gemfile to rspec-rails 2.7.0, rspec-core 2.7.1 and ran bundle install which solved the problem for me.

Running rails 3.1.1. Also spork 0.9.0.rc9 if that interests you.